# How to fix another route Vue.js on Node.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js

i build vuejs using  "npm run build" and get dist folder. in a dist folder have index.html file.
on a nodejs server file index.js i write my code "app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))" for run index.html for show my website, but another route not working. like a "/" is working but "/about" not working how to fix it.
thankyou very much

Comment: are you using vue-router?

Comment: I would recommend serving your `dist` folder through nginX.

Answer (score 0):

you cant change your dist folder ,
your vue js code have some bug ,
you should fix them, after fix it build your site again

send your route file "/about"

thats have some bug

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain

Comment: your code have some bug, you cant fix them whith change dist(build file) you should fix the orginal code , then build your code and create new dist(build file)